# Move ListView data to new screen onClick

Tags: java, android, listview, listviewitem

I have a listview on my MainActivity. I have set up an onLongClickListener to open a MapsActivity when any of the listview items are long pressed.

How can I copy the contents of the listview item that is pressed to the MapsActivity?

<s>How can I copy one of the fields (e.g. an address field) from the listview item that is long pressed to the MapsActivity?</s>  Below is the code in the listener with an intent filter to open the MapsActivity.

```
 list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //Open Maps Activity
            Intent k = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);

            Calendar c = (Calendar)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            startActivity(k);
            return true;
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setonItemSelected listener this gives you the position of the selected item you can then get data corresponding to that position and display it

Comment: I've had a look at setonItemSelected. If I'm understanding it correctly I don't think it's what I'm looking for. I have edited the original post to hopefully explain what I'm trying to do better

Comment: when you have set the adapter for your listview you must be passing an arraylist right ? . So when you click on a certain item use it's position to get the object from your array list then pass the values as extras to your MapsActivity

Comment: Does the line: `Calendar c = (Calendar)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);` not give me the value at the position selected?

Comment: No , you must have written somewhere list.setAdapter and then passed an  arraylist as an arguement use that arraylist to get the item 
suppose you passed myList use myListe.get(position) to get the object

Comment: Oh, I think I see. In a different method called populateList() I have the following code `ArrayList<Calendar> calendars = calendarEventDatabaseHelper.getEventsList();

        CalendarAdapter adapter = new CalendarAdapter (this, calendars);

        list.setAdapter(adapter);`. So I want to use Calendar.get(position)?

Comment: Yes . If it doesn't work give me your source code i will try to fix it

Comment: I haven't had any luck, here's the code I've got so far. https://pastebin.com/CDjjedyY

Comment: I've had a look, using intent.putExtra with the key's is the bit that I've not been able to get working, but your code helped show me how to do that. Thanks!

Comment: Glad i could be of help